# Opening question from notification panel while already opened

Tags: bug, android-app

Doing so adds a new view instance to the stack instead of checking it's already opened. Can be done multiple times.

Prerequisite :

1. Have a notification

How to reproduce:

1. Open notification panel
2. Press new notification
3. Open notification panel
4. Press same notification
5. Press back

Nexus 5

Android 6.0.1

App version 1.0.83